# How can I display the value of fastLine on Maximum custom axisY

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I use a .NET Winform version teechart 4.1.2012.1032.

I use custom y axis & fastLine. 
Look at the below picture.
Maximum axisY is 100. And I want keep this. 
Look at the red circle. Line is not displayed if the value 100 . 
Other values ​​were shown .
How can I display ?

[image]

Another problem. Maximum grid line is not displayed. How can I solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the MaximumOffset property in the axis, for example:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Left.MaximumOffset = 10;
```

Alternatively you can hide the back wall combined with a minimal *MaximumOffset* as in this example:

```
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Walls.Back.Visible = false;

  FastLine fastLine1 = new FastLine(tChart1.Chart);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    int tmp = ((i > 40) && (i < 60)) ? 100 : i;
    fastLine1.Add(tmp);
  }

  tChart1.Axes.Left.MaximumOffset = 1;
```

which produces this chart:

[image]

Comment: Yes.  I did it.  But when  i did it, the maximum value was changed. I want to keep it, 100. And i use custom axisY.

Comment: @DugSungKim ok, I have extended my reply suggesting to hide the back wall instead.

Comment: Thank. I solved it. But another problem is occurred. Look at the above picture. Maximum grid line is not displayed. How can I solve it?

Comment: @DugSungKim ok, I have extended my answer once again. Combining back wall hiding with a 1 pixel MaximumOffset solves it.

Comment: Thank you but It's not solved. Because I use "Labels.RoundFirstLabel = false". In this case,result is not appeared as a your example. I must set Labels.RoundFirstLabel = false, Left.Automatic = false, Left.Increment = (max-min) / 10, because I keep min,max as a labels. For example SetMinMax(1, 99), axis label must be displayed as min = 1, max = 99, and vertical grid division counts is 10.

Comment: @DugSungKim ok, could you please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here so that we can provide an accurate and effective solution to your problem? You can post your files at  www.steema.net/upload/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded sample project.

Comment: @DugSungKim thanks for the example project. I can reproduce the problem with it. I see you used TeeChart 4.1.2012.1032. It works fine with the latest TeeChart for .NET version (build 4.1.2014.12150-4). You might be interested in renewing your subscription or upgrading your license at http://www.steema.com/order. For sales inquiries please contact sales@steema.com. You can also download the fully functional evaluation version at http://www.steema.com/download/net

Comment: @DugSungKim you're very welcome. If you think my post answered your question correctly you may consider voting for it and accepting the answer. Thanks.